# CSS Circular placement around parent's center

Tags: css

I want to create a circular placement of divs around the parent's center point.
Like this:
[image]

What I have achieved right now was this:

https://codepen.io/wagnerpaz/pen/qBrYeKb

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="item" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: red; transform: rotate(0deg)"></div>
      <div class="item" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: black; transform: rotate(60deg)"></div>
      <div class="item" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: blue; transform: rotate(120deg)"></div>
      <div class="item" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: yellow; transform: rotate(180deg)"></div>
      <div class="item" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: purple; transform: rotate(240deg)"></div>
      <div class="item" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: gray; transform: rotate(300deg)"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 300%;
}
```

Comment: here is a more relevant duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65863788/8620333

Comment: also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66930542/8620333